# Custom default referances for Solution Visual C# 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to configure the current solution such that every new project created (or imported possibly) has references that you can configure rather than having to go through every project and add reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure solution for adding references to newly created/imported projects. But you can export a project template based on your project:

1. Create new project
2. Add desired references to this project
3. Invoke File -> Export Template... menu item
4. Select "Project Template" option and desired project in combo-box
5. Set template name on next page and click finish

Now you can create project from template you've created and it will have references you've added on step 2.